# Group By Lists python

Tags: python, list

```
tests= ['test-2017-09-19-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-19-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-07-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-06-12-07']
```

So I have the above list, how could I group by the list such that I can get a list which looks like the one below:

```
[['test-2017-09-19-12-06','test-2017-09-19-12-05'],
 ['test-2017-09-12-12-06','test-2017-09-12-12-05'],
 ['test-2017-09-07-12-05'],
 ['test-2017-09-06-12-07']]
```

I did try the following code but I get different results, where each string value becomes its own list rather than group by.

```
from itertools import groupby

print([list(j) for i, j in groupby(tests)])
```

Comment: Where do you get `'test-2017-09-12-12-06'` in your desired output from?

Comment: @ForceBru those are file names stored in a particular directory. And I can not change the naming convention (which I tried) to make it easier to do a group by.

Comment: @MooingRawr the only difference in the names is the digits at the end of each string i.e -06 and -05, anything before that on the same day remains the same. for example 'test-2017-09-19-12-06' and 'test-2017-09-19-12-05', the difference here is -06 and -05 but 'test-2017-09-19-12' is the same in both.

Comment: I understand, but this particular entry doesn't figure in the original list, hence the question: where does it come from?

Comment: @ForceBru my bad let me edit the post. 
Edit: I changed the post. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that range 0:15, you can use that to determine which segment is used for the grouping.

```
tests= ['test-2017-09-19-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-19-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-07-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-06-12-07']

pprint.pprint([list(j[1]) for j in groupby(tests,lambda i:i[0:15])])
[['test-2017-09-19-12-06', 'test-2017-09-19-12-05'],
 ['test-2017-09-12-12-05', 'test-2017-09-12-12-05'],
 ['test-2017-09-07-12-05'],
 ['test-2017-09-06-12-07']]
```

Comment: I tried your code but it returns one big list rather than group by 
        [['test-2017-09-19-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-19-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-07-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-06-12-07']]

Comment: @shabbzy if you need the groupby iterator then just use `groupby(tests,lambda i:i[0:15])`

Comment: @shabbzy I saw you added a comment, you can also replace that `0:15` for  `0:-2` if you only want to group by the last two characters of the string.

Comment: @shabbzy also, bear in mind that if those are filenames and there is an extension (which you don't show in your example), then you need to do `0:-6` to account for the 3 characters in the extension plus the dot.

Comment: @shabbzy no problem, there is a green tick next to the answer's vote count that you can use to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it with by size

```
tests = ['test-2017-09-19-12-06',
        'test-2017-09-19-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-12-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-07-12-05',
        'test-2017-09-06-12-07']
size = 2
[tests[i:i+size] for i  in range(0, len(tests), size)]
```

Comment: What if the data is more than 2 size apart? ie what if you don't know the size

Comment: @Sarah Hastings the data can be more i.e there can be more than 2, how could I take that into consideration?

Comment: @shabbzy You can also use `[tests[i::size] for i in range(size)]` where you can define the number of sublist you want. So for example, if you want three sets (sublists), you will use size = 3, if you want two sets, you can use size = 2

Comment: I'm guessin OP doesn't know how many items there are in each group beforehand, that's why he wants to use `groupby`.